# magit 2 equivalent of . command to mark commit

Tags: emacs, magit

Many magit tutorials still online as of September 2015 (e.g. [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-magit-emacs-mode-git), [here](http://vickychijwani.me/magit-part-ii/), and [here](http://daemianmack.com/magit-cheatsheet.html)) are based on magit 1.x, and describe a diff workflow where the user marks a start commit with <kbd>.</kbd> and then moves point to the end commit and invokes diff with <kbd>=</kbd>.  Using point and mark for this seems very nice in emacs, and other commands also operate on the marked commit.

Magit 2.x has many great new features but there's no longer a mark command, and I'm having trouble finding a good equivalent of this mark-and-diff workflow.  From the log view you can type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to diff a range, but then you have to type in both commit hashes or references.  Is there some other way in magit 2.x that I have missed to mark-and-diff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark a region, and calling either `magit-diff` (`dr`) or
`magit-diff-dwim` (`dd`) will compare the two commits at the bounds.